# Cannot install pyaudio

Tags: python, audio

I've been trying to install/build pyaudio with little success. When I try to build it from the source, I get this:

```
pi@pi:~/pyaudio $ sudo python setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing src/PyAudio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/PyAudio.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/PyAudio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-armv6l/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-armv6l-2.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:23: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
 #include "portaudio.h"
                       ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Needless to say, I have installed portaudio (built from source). Trying to install pyaudio or portaudio or any dependency gives me 'unable to locate package'. What am I missing?

Comment: try this sudo apt install portaudio-dev then rerun the above command. You can also try this sudo apt-get install libportaudio2

Answer (score 2):

Ref: https://engineeringlearning.blogspot.com/2017/08/installing-pyaudio-on-debian-on.html

1. `sudo apt-get install libasound-dev`
2. `sudo apt-get install portaudio19-dev`
3. `pip install pyaudio --user`
4. `sudo apt-get install python3-pyaudio`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I installed Stretch and things were straightforward from then on.